# Activity Indicator doesn't appear on swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, swift4

I am using WebKit View and trying to show an activity indicator before my page loads, but the activity indicator doesn't appear.

There is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }

 func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    actInd.startAnimating()
 }

 func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    actInd.stopAnimating()
 }
```

Comment: check if your activity indicator is behind your webview

Comment: check if your delegates work

Comment: @eneadume if delegate don't work the activity indicator should be visible but without animation

Comment: are you seen this `var webView: WKWebView!` its `WKWebView` not `UIWebView` then how the delegate will call, see this for e.g for [WKWebView](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/05/creating-simple-browser-with-wkwebview.html)

Comment: @ThreeCoins Works fine making like your example. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @FelipeSilva - welcome my bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to stopping the activity indicator, you might want to hide it once the url stops loading. I achieved this by editing the func webViewDidFinishLoad

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    actInd.stopAnimating()
    actInd.hidesWhenStopped = true
 }
```

This hides the activity indicator when the url has completed loading

Answer (score 0):

You are using  **WKWebView** and trying to use **UIWebView** **Delegate**

if you are familiar with UIWebView delegate means use UIWebView instead of WKWebView and set delegate before load url

```
webView.delegate = self
```

or you need to use WKWebView delegate